# Script not waiting for & threads to finish

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing, scripting

I have a bash script that dumps specific databases based on the result of a database query. I've simplified the script excerpt for the purpose of resolving this issue.

The script runs fine, but wanting to speed things up, I wrapped the mysqldump command in the while loop with the { }& and added a 'wait' after the 'done', but it doesn't wait.

The same methods works fine in a similar script that uses a 'for' loop, where it waits for all threads to complete, but I'm unsure why this one is progressing to the subsequent steps of the script and not 'wait'ing.
Any ideas?

```
 mysql --defaults-extra-file=XX.cnf -N -e "SELECT dbname FROM table" | while IFS= read -r dbname
    do
    {
        echo "Doing stuff with  $dbname"
                
        mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=XX.cnf --opt  --databases  "$dbname" > dump_"${dbname}".sql 

        echo "${dbname} dump complete"
    }  &
done 
wait
```

Answer (score 2):

The parts of the pipeline are run in a subshell. You started background processes in a subshell. You can't wait on processes started by a subshell in the parent shell. You can wait only on processes started by the same shell that started them.

Make sure you wait in the same shell that started them. Like:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=XX.cnf -N -e "SELECT dbname FROM table" | {
  while IFS= read -r dbname; do
    {
       echo "Doing stuff with  $dbname"
       mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=XX.cnf --opt  --databases  "$dbname" > dump_"${dbname}".sql 
       echo "${dbname} dump complete"
    }  &
  done 
  wait
}
```

Comment: I'd just clocked that myself and posted my own answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Doh!
the pipe is creating a subshell!

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=XX.cnf -N -e "SELECT dbname FROM table" |  ( while IFS= read -r dbname
do
{
    echo "Dumping $dbname"

    mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=XX.cnf --opt  --databases  "$dbname" > dump_"${dbname}".sql


    echo "${dbname} dump complete"

}  &
```

done
wait
)